# Far Manager NetBox SFTP can't connect to the linux server

Tags: linux, sftp, redhat, far, netbox

I'm trying to connect to the RedHat Linux server through Far Manager 3.0.5800.0 x64 and NetBox plugin with SFTP. But it doesn't open the session as I expect it and doesn't exposure any errors. The connection screen blinks once and disappears, get me back to the NetBox: Stored sessions panel.

I CAN connect to that server through putty ssh, and it seems to be completely ok.
I CAN connect through Far Manager to THAT server as a different user also as a root user.

[image]

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Got it, thank you, I will.

Comment: No idea how to delete it from here. It says: You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.

Comment: Delete your answer and then delete your question?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that I recently wrote in the .bashrc file some strings with "echo" command. And it seems to be after that the NetBox doesn't want to establish a session by that user.

So just inspect your .bashrc file and clean all echo commands.